# Не работает IndexOf

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть данный участок кода:

```
const arrayOfIds = teacher.testsCreated.map(test => (test.id));
console.log(arrayOfIds);
console.log(test._id);
console.log(arrayOfIds.indexOf(test._id));
```

Вот что выводит консоль:

```
[ 5942d0d03c5918c49f67588a, 594fa2a704e7ac0fc4bfc3ad ]
594fa2a704e7ac0fc4bfc3ad
-1
```

Почему -1 а не 1?

Comment: рабочий пример можно какой-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что в значениях `id` у вас пробелы, которые, видимо, надо обрезать

```
const arrayOfIds = teacher.testsCreated.map(test => (test.id.trim()));
```